# How to get the root directory for the java script code?

Tags: javascript

In a HTML page, how do I discover the root directory using Javascript?

```
var x = tinyMCEPopup.editor.getContent().toString();
$.ajax({
    url: '/TinyEditor/XML/PreviewBody.xml', //read xml
    type: 'get', //method type
    dataType: 'xml', //c
```

Look at the URL and I made changed in the jscript library and that exist in the `.html` page extension.
I have to hard code the above URl, the whole application is kept in the root directory TinyEditor on the server, in case this directory name is changed then, my code will be not function proper, that's why i need to find a way to get the root directory in a generalize way.
Got my point?

Comment: For no reason, you put a negative mark and 1 close tag too? Justify it why is done?

Comment: I did a research for this.. and i don't see any solution that's why i posted it here, my question is credible and has efforts.

Comment: you can make a php page instead of a html page and use some variables in a heredoc block. but it is not directly possible in normal javascript (maybe something like nodejs?)

Comment: No reason? The question is _in_ credibly bad (for starters, it makes no sense.. now you justify why this was done), and you have shown _zero_ evidence of any effort whatsoever.

Comment: What even is a "root directory for JavaScript"? I don't understand what you want to know. Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Do you need to know the `server` root directory (for example: `C:\MyProject\MyPage.html`) ? Or do you need to know the URL root directory (for example: `http://www.example.com/`)?

Comment: @Max;- for the above code i think i need to know the server root directory.

Comment: The browser does not care about the server root directory. It can only understand and access URLs (if the content is not on the same machine). Instead of *assuming* a solution to your problem, you should clearly state your problem.

Answer (score 3):

From both Javascript and HTML, the website domain's root directory is `/`.

Comment: The question is valid so is the answer. I Stumbled upon it because I couldnt access an mp3 file from js from a subfolder while it worked fine from root folder. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't: JavaScript runs on the client side, so it doesn't know anything about the server's directories.

Comment: You're being too technical. Once the website is loaded into the browser (client side) what is the root folder of the loaded website. I found the question valid and so was the first answer. Helped me resolve my issue.